# Name of countries are not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why it displays [object Object]? I'm trying to display a selection of countries. See the example code.

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{

  const selectDrop = document.querySelector('#countries');
 
  
  fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res => {
    return res.json();
  }).then(data => {
      let output = "";
    data.forEach(country => {

      output += `<option>${country.name}</option>`;
    })
    selectDrop.innerHTML = output;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  
  });
```

Comment: Add the what `data` looks like

Answer (score 3):

it should be `country.name.common`

country.name is an object

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{

  const selectDrop = document.querySelector('#countries');
 
  
  fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res => {
    return res.json();
  }).then(data => {
      const output = data.map(d => d.name.common)
                         .sort()
                         .map(name => `<option>${name}</option>`)
                         .join('')
    selectDrop.innerHTML = output;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  
  });
```

```html
<select id="countries"></select>
```

I edited the code to add `sort`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your data and it structure is something like this:

```js
"name":{
  "common":"Bulgaria",
  "official":"Republic of Bulgaria",
  ...
}
```

You need to access the property like `country.name.common`